# $x' = \alpha \tan x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to qualitatively study the system $$x' = \alpha \tan x$$

I was asked to analyze as a function of $\alpha$ the maximal interval of definition of the solution in terms of $(t_0, x_0)$. I am supposed to do this without explicitly solving the equation.

Since $\tan x$ is continously differentiable in $(-\tfrac{\pi}{2}, \tfrac{\pi}{2})$ and is undefined in $\pm \tfrac{\pi}{2}$ the solutions are defined as long as $|x(t)| < \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. In particular, the solutions are undefined if $x_0 = \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. $x_0 = 0$ is the stationary solution $x(t) = 0$, defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\alpha < 0$ then the system seems to me to be stable around the origin and I would expect solutions to be defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\alpha > 0$ then $|x(t)|$ is an increasing function and I think the interval of existence will be finite and will be smaller the greater is $\alpha$.

Are these hypothesis correct? Is there a way to formalize them?

Comment: For $u=\sin(x)$ you get $u'=αu$, if you want to compare your qualitative analysis with an exact solution.

Comment: You could also switch variables and consider $t'=\frac{\cot (x)}{\alpha }$